# deleting table row using ajax not working

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, pdo

I am creating a simple question/reply page using ajax and everything else is working such as posting questions, posting replies but when it comes to deleting a reply it is just refusing to do so, at one point it was working then I changed something, reverted it in my text editor and now its deciding to not work anymore...

I keep getting this error:

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 41 column 1 of
> the JSON data

and no matter how I change the response part its not making any difference.

This is the page for displaying the replies...

```
<?php
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM `replies` WHERE `title` = :title");
$stmt->bindParam(':title', $fetch2['title']);
$stmt->execute();
$replies = $stmt->fetchAll();

if (count($replies) == 0) {
echo '
  <center>
    <div class="col-lg-12" style="text-align:left;">
      <br><br>
      <small style="font-weight:bolder;padding:4px 12px;">No Replies Yet!</small><br><br>
      <hr style="background-color:#333;color:#333;height:1px;border:none;">
    </div>
  </center>
';
} else {

foreach ($replies as $reply) {

?>

<div class="" style="margin:0 auto;max-width:1280px;display:inline-flex;margin-bottom:12px;">
  <img src="/images/uploads/<?php echo $reply['img'];?>" style="width:42px;border-radius:50%;">
  <small style="margin-left:12px;"><b><?php echo $reply['username'];?></b></small>
</div>

<?php if ($userID == $reply['userID'] && $userdetails == $reply['username']): ?>

<div style="float:right;" class="dropdown">
  <iconify-icon role="button" aria-expanded="false" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-custom" icon="gridicons:ellipsis" style="color:#888;float:right;"></iconify-icon>
  <style>
    /* Hide the default dropdown arrow for the custom class */
    .dropdown-toggle-custom::after {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="background-color:#212529;color:#fff;">
    <li>
      <a style="color:black;" class="dropdown-item" href="#">Report Reply</a>
      <form id="delete-reply-form-<?php echo $reply['id']; ?>" action="/PHP/user_functions.php" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $reply['id'];?>" name="id">
        <button class="dropdown-item deleteReply" name="deleteReply">Delete</button>
      </form>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<?php else: ?>

<div style="float:right;" class="dropdown">
  <iconify-icon role="button" aria-expanded="false" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-custom" icon="gridicons:ellipsis" style="color:#888;float:right;"></iconify-icon>
  <style>
    /* Hide the default dropdown arrow for the custom class */
    .dropdown-toggle-custom::after {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="background-color:#212529;color:#fff;">
    <li>
      <a style="color:black;" class="dropdown-item" href="#">Report Reply</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<?php endif; ?>

<br>

<div class="R" style="margin:0 auto;padding-left:6px;">
 <small style=""><?php echo $reply['reply'];?></small>
</div>

<small style="color:#666;float:right;">Replied: <?php echo date("d/m/Y" ,strtotime($reply['date']));?></small>

<hr style="background-color:#333;color:#333;height:1px;border:none;">

<?php
}}
?>

 <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $(document).on("click", ".deleteReply", function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();

 var formData = {
 'id': $(this).closest('form').find('input[name="id"]').val()
 };

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "/PHP/user_functions.php",
data: formData,
dataType: 'json',
success: function(response) {
console.log(response);
alert("Reply deleted successfully!");
$('#delete-reply-form-<?php echo $reply['id']; ?>')[0].reset();
},
error: function(xhr, status, error) {
console.log(error);
alert("An error occurred while deleting the reply.");
}
});
});
});
</script>`
```

and here is my user_functions.php..

EDIT - Changes made to the user_functions.php, still getting error:

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 47 column 1 of
> the JSON data

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['deleteReply'])) {
$id = $_POST['id'];

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("DELETE FROM `replies` WHERE `id` = :id");
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
$stmt->execute();

// Prepare the JSON response
$response = array('success' => true, 'message' => 'Reply deleted successfully');

// Set the response header as JSON
header('Content-Type: application/json');
// Send the JSON response
echo json_encode($response);
exit();
}
?>
```

Now I'm trying like this... but I keep getting object error now:

> Object { success: false, message: "An error occurred while deleting
> the reply" }

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$(document).on("click", ".deleteReply", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var formData = {
        'id': $(this).closest('form').find('input[name="id"]').val()
    };

    console.log(formData);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/PHP/user_functions.php",
        data: formData,
        dataType: 'json'
    })
    .done(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        if (response.success) {
            alert(response.message);
            $('#delete-reply-form-<?php echo $reply['id']; ?>')[0].reset();
        } else {
            alert(response.message);
        }
    })
    .fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
        alert("An error occurred while deleting the reply.");
    });
   });
 });
</script>


<?php
if (isset($_POST['deleteReply'])) {
    $id = $_POST['id'];

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("DELETE FROM `replies` WHERE `id` = :id");
    $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);

    $success = $stmt->execute();

    if ($success && $stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
        // Reply was deleted successfully
        $response = array('success' => true, 'message' => 'Reply deleted successfully');
    } elseif ($success && $stmt->rowCount() === 0) {
        // No rows were affected
        $response = array('success' => false, 'message' => 'Reply deletion failed: No matching reply found');
    } else {
        // Reply deletion failed
        $response = array('success' => false, 'message' => 'Reply deletion failed');
    }

    // Set the response header as JSON
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    // Send the JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
    exit();
}

// If the code reaches here, an error occurred
$response = array('success' => false, 'message' => 'An error occurred while deleting the reply');
// Set the response header as JSON
header('Content-Type: application/json');
// Send the JSON response
echo json_encode($response);
exit();
?>
```

Comment: Your AJAX code expects `user_functions.php` to return JSON. But it's redirecting back to the referrer, which is HTML. It gets an error when it tries to parse that as JSON.

Comment: Fix the script to return JSON as expected.

Comment: @Barmar I have added to the bottom of my question what I've tried and its still giving me "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 47 column 1 of the JSON data"

Comment: Then use the browser's Network tool to examine the raw response of the request to user_functions.php and check what it _actually_ returned. Presumably, it wasn't JSON (or wasn't entirely JSON).

Comment: @ADyson In the console I get Request Payload: id=11 and in the response I get 23 blank lines and then "{"success":false,"message":"An error occurred while deleting the reply"}" on the 24th line. I'm using the latest code at the bottom of my question

Comment: You need to find out why deletion failed, then. Turn on PDO exceptions mode so you can get proper sql errors

Comment: First to troubleshoot is your $_POST values check $_POST['deleteReply'] and $_POST['id'] and try to comment your SQL query  first. try to echo it it must be response 200. if success then your query is the problem try to concatenate  first your parameters to query string and return it again. check if no syntax error on query.

Comment: I don't see where your PHP code ever sets `'success' => false` in the JSON. That must not be the same PHP that you're actually using.

Comment: @Barmar it's in the very last snippet of code - keep scrolling past the ajax stuff...

Comment: @ADyson I thought that was the JavaScript snippet, I was looking in the PHP before it :)

Comment: @Barmar yeah its not very clear...I think that's version 2 of the code, but all in one block this time

Answer (score 0):

You get that error when there's no `deleteReply` key in `$_POST`. Your `$.ajax()` call doesn't specify `deleteReply` in the `formData`. You need to add it:

```
    var formData = {
        'id': $(this).closest('form').find('input[name="id"]').val(),
        'deleteReply': 1
    };
```

This would be sent automatically if you were submitting the form using that button. But since you're using AJAX, it only sends the fields that you specify explicitly in `formData`.